# Why getting error when trying to create ad creative to boost instagram post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been working with Instagram Ad API and trying to boost an Instagram Post using Instagram Ad API.

But getting this error when trying to create an adcreative.

I tried to create adcreative in Graph API Explorer with this POST Request
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_AD_ACOOUNT_ID/adcreatives?object_id=PAGE_ID&instagram_user_id=PAGE_ID&source_instagram_media_id=INSTAGRAM_POST_ID along with user access token

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1487390,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Adcreative Create Failed",
    "error_user_msg": "The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: Something went wrong. Please try again later",
    "fbtrace_id": "A1EIGCSD2fRpnuila1bq4c6"
  }
}
```

Reason for this error not mentioned in error_user_msg.
What is the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Thank You.